# Python how to change the size of screenshot from googlemap by PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-maps, pyqt4

Recently I use PyQt4 to capture the webpage of google map.
But the size of the image of screenshot is not exactly I see on the google map

Here is the result by PyQt4

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMYdb.jpg

But the original web is like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS5rh.jpg

It looks like it only captured the central part of the web page.

Can someone help me to fix the problem?

Here is the code of capturing the web page as an image

```
class Screenshot(QWebView):
def __init__(self):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QWebView.__init__(self)
    self._loaded = False
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)

def capture(self, url, output_file):
    self.load(QUrl(url))
    self.wait_load()
    # set to webpage size
    frame = self.page().mainFrame()
    #print frame.contentsSize()
    self.page().setViewportSize(frame.contentsSize())
    # render image
    image = QImage(self.page().viewportSize(), QImage.Format_ARGB32)
    painter = QPainter(image)
    frame.render(painter)
    painter.end()
    print 'saving', output_file
    image.save(output_file)

def wait_load(self, delay=0):
    # process app events until page loaded
    while not self._loaded:
        self.app.processEvents()
        time.sleep(delay)
    self._loaded = False

def _loadFinished(self, result):
    self._loaded = True
```

I tried to manually set the size of view port (see below), but it did not work...

```
self.page().setViewportSize(PyQt4.QtCore.QSize(1280, 480))
```

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PyQt to do that operation, use a specialized module for screenshots like:

[ImageGrab](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagegrab.htm)

The example they have on their page seems quite helpful:

```
    im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

    if isinstance(im, Image.Image):
        ... got an image ...
    elif im:
       for filename in im:
           try:
               im = Image.open(filename)
           except IOError:
               pass # ignore this file
           else:
               ... got an image ...
    else:
        ... clipboard empty ...
```

Since ImageGrab works with [PIL (or Pillow)](http://python-pillow.org/) you should be able to have a lot more control about the image.

Comment: Thank you so much, but this is not exactly what I am asking! Anyway, I have already solved the problem, thanks~

Comment: Than you should post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The problem is in gmplot.py. I use this module to generate the googlemap. However, in the gmplot.py, there was  f.write(
            '\t<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>\n') and I changed it to  f.write(
            '\t<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1280px; height: 1280px;"></div>\n').